# Mariadb explain output is strange

Tags: indexing, mariadb, explain

```
id:'1', 
select_type: 'SIMPLE', 
table: 's', 
type: 'index', 
possible_keys: 'PRIMARY',
key: 't_sensors_sensor_type_id_fk', 
key_len: '2', 
ref: NULL, 
rows: '4', 
Extra: 'Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

My question is: 
Possible keys column is right, but key column is wrong, mariadb chooses index which are not presented in possible keys, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not MariaDB-specific, see MySQL manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

> It is possible that key will name an index that is not present in the
>   possible_keys value. This can happen if none of the possible_keys
>   indexes are suitable for looking up rows, but all the columns selected
>   by the query are columns of some other index. That is, the named index
>   covers the selected columns, so although it is not used to determine
>   which rows to retrieve, an index scan is more efficient than a data
>   row scan.